# UIAlertController only shows up the first time it needs to be presented

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have a table with cells that each have `UISwitches` on them. If a switch is toggled and there is no internet connection, I want to present an `UIAlertController` that says "No Internet Connection".

Here's the `@IBAction` for a flip of the switch I have in my custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func switchFlipped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if Methods.sharedInstance.hasConnectivity() {

        //Actions if there is internet connectivity

    } else {

        self.switch.on = !switch.on

        let subscriptionsVC = self.delegate as! SubscriptionsTableViewController
        subscriptionsVC.presentViewController(subscriptionsVC.networkConnectivityError, animated: false,completion: nil)
        subscriptionsVC.view.sendSubviewToBack(subscriptionsVC.view)

    }

}
```

The first time I flip a switch with no internet connection, everything works fine. The second time though, the screen is greyed out but the actual alert doesn't show up and the user is stuck. What is going on?

Comment: Generally, you don't hold on to references to other controllers how you have `subscriptionsVC.networkConnectivityError`. Better to just create the controller inside of `switchFlipped` (move this code into a different function if it's a lot, but create it each time inside of `switchFlipped` instead of trying to re-present the same controller).

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea to use delegation, but the `switchFlipped` method should invoke a method on your delegate (your table view controller).  That delegate method should then handle the network check & alert display.  The force downcast provides a hint that you aren't handling this in the best way.

Comment: Thank you @ConnorNeville, I moved the creation of the alert into the switch flipped method and it works now.